# TIme of execution of daily anacron job

Tags: cron

I have set a daily anacron job, which runs form `/etc/cron.daily`.  From the `/etc/crontab` I see it should run daily at 06:25 (or at start-up/reboot).

However when the date changes (`00:00`) and the computer is up, I don't want anacron to wait till 06:25. If the computer is up I would like to it to run the script as soon as the date changes (`00:00`). Does it make sense to add a cron job to run anacron `@hourly`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Ubuntu 19.10 (and maybe earlier) `anacron` is run using a `systemd` timer.

## Solution

The way to change `anacron` execution time is with this command:

```
sudo systemctl edit --full anacron.timer
```

Then modify the line:

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* 07..23:30
```

## What doesn't work

As explained in other answers, editing `/etc/crontab` doesn't help.

```
25 7    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

The part before the operator `||` only tests if `anacron` is installed, it doesn't execute anything. And the part after only get executed if the part before didn't complete successfully (lazy operator evaluation), which then would mean `anacron` isn't installed.

Editing `/etc/cron.d/anacron` doesn't help either.

```
30 7-23 * * *   root    [ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi
```

The condition `if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]` prevents the script from running when systemd is installed.

The correct way to change the execution time is by editing the `systemd` timer as explained at the begining.

Comment: And that, my dear friends, is one of the many reasons one should consider Devuan Linux (or Artix)

Answer (score 7):

I found how to do this.

If you want to change the behaviour of `anacron` to execute as soon as the day changes (and not wait till `7:30` as is the default behaviour) do the following:

```
gksu gedit /etc/cron.d/anacron
```

and add the last 2 lines (the last line will restart anacron every hour):

```
01 0    * * *   root test -x /etc/init.d/anacron && /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null
01 0    * * *   root start -q anacron || :
@hourly root start -q anacron || :
```

Comment: There's a problem with the formatting of your file snippet. I can't tell what you intended, but the "| :" that currently resides *outside* the code block is almost certainly intended to be *somewhere* in it.

Comment: your link to your blog post seems broken.

Comment: This answer is wrong for any systems using systemd.  See the correct answer by @Jocelyn from June 20 2020.

Answer (score 7):

The [answer by Khaled](https://askubuntu.com/a/92951/117103) is not correct. Changing this line will not have an effect if `anacron` is installed (which it is, by default):

```
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

If anacron exists, `test -x /usr/sbin/anacron` will return `true`, and prevent the second half of that line from running. The other answer (editing `/etc/cron.d/anacron`) is correct, since that's the config that will kick off anacron itself.

Comment: This answer is wrong for any systems using systemd.  See the correct answer by @Jocelyn from June 20 2020.

Answer (score 3):

as per other answers:

edit the first two columns of `/etc/cron.d/anacron` to change the time anachron runs.

(`/etc/crontab` values don't take effect due to the `|| ...`)

Comment: This answer is wrong for any systems using systemd.  See the correct answer by @Jocelyn from June 20 2020.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the line:

```
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

to read

```
0 0    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

This will make the execution of daily cron jobs start at midnight.

Comment: -1 This is not related to anacron execution time. If anacron is installed, these lines do nothing. See ``/etc/cron.d/anacron`` to change execution time of anacron.

Comment: This answer is wrong for any systems using systemd.  See the correct answer by @Jocelyn from June 20 2020.